# Rebuild MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'users' with two columns: 'id' and 'username'. Now 2 rows in that table with 'Bill' and 'Mike'. I need check this table contains
3 users: 'Bill', 'Mike' and 'Sarah'.

Query

```
select username from users where username in ('Bill', 'Mike', 'Sarah');
```

returns me result

```
         username |
-------------------
  Bill            | 
-------------------
  Mike            |
-------------------
```

but i need result like that

```
     username     | has |
-------------------------
  Bill            |  1  |
-------------------------
  Mike            |  1  |
-------------------------
  Sarah           |  0  |
-------------------------
```

My database is MySql. How can i rebuild my query?

I want always 3 rows. If 'Sarah' will be added, then result must be:

```
     username     | has |
-------------------------
  Bill            |  1  |
-------------------------
  Mike            |  1  |
-------------------------
  Sarah           |  1  |
-------------------------
```

If table is empty, then result must be:

```
     username     | has |
-------------------------
  Bill            |  0  |
-------------------------
  Mike            |  0  |
-------------------------
  Sarah           |  0  |
-------------------------
```

Comment: So there's no Sarah in your table, but you still want that name to be returned?

Comment: And what is the "has" column supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one: //there may be a typo error

```
select username, Count(username) as has from users 
where username in ('Bill', 'Mike', 'Sarah')
UNION
select username, 0 as has from
(select username, 1 as has from ('Bill')
UNION ALL
select username, 1 as has from ('Mike')
UNION ALL
select username, 1 as has from ('Sarah'))
```

Comment: If all users exist wouldn't you get 2 rows each.  1 with 1 for has the and the other with 0?

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
select c.username, count(u.username) as has 
from (select 'Bill' as username union select 'Mike' union select 'Sarah') as c
join users as u on c.username = u.username
group by c.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AllUsers.UserName,  CASE WHEN U2.UserName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Has
FROM
(SELECT UserName 
FROM [User] U 
WHERE U.UserName in ('Bill', 'Mike', 'Sarah')
UNION
SELECT 'Bill'
UNION 
SELECT 'Mike'
UNION
SELECT 'Sarah') AllUsers
LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] U2 ON U2.UserName = AllUsers.UserName
```